# Creating fake data using date logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I am trying to insert fake data into this table. It can't be totally random because the rows would need to make sense. I'll explain below.

My data looks like this:

| AcctID | account_status | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C382861922 | ACTIVE | 2016-05-25 | None |
| C382861922 | INACTIVE | None | None |
| C382861922 | ACTIVE | None | None |
| C382861922 | INACTIVE | None | 2021-12-31 |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | 2015-12-27 | None |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | None | 2021-12-31 |
| C643625629 | ACTIVE | 2016-07-24 | None |
| C643625629 | INACTIVE | None | None |
| C643625629 | ACTIVE | None | 2021-12-31 |
| C82157435 | ACTIVE | 2016-10-22 | None |
| C82157435 | INACTIVE | None | 2021-12-31 |

Each AcctID can appear multiple times, but it's easiest to explain what I'm doing with just an example where the AcctID appears twice:

| AcctID | account_status | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C82157435 | ACTIVE | 2016-10-22 | None |
| C82157435 | INACTIVE | None | 2021-12-31 |

My goal is to **randomly pick a date** where this customer changed their account_status, **which would become both the end_date of the first row and the start_date of the 2nd row**. So, I only need to pick 1 random date, and insert it in both places. Easy enough - I can max() and min() and then calculate the difference in days, and then choose a random integer within that range.

However, **I can't figure out how I'd do it for a customer with using more than 2 records**:

| AcctID | account_status | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | 2015-12-27 | None |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | None | None |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | None | 2021-12-31 |

There will be several places to choose a random date, but since they need to correspond to each other, the problem becomes really complex. Any ideas?

Here's code to create the sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

fake = [
 {
   "AcctID": "C429768513",
   "account_status": "ACTIVE",
   "start_date": "2015-12-27",
   "end_date": "None"
 },
 {
   "AcctID": "C429768513",
   "account_status": "INACTIVE",
   "start_date": "None",
   "end_date": "None"
 },
 {
   "AcctID": "C429768513",
   "account_status": "ACTIVE",
   "start_date": "None",
   "end_date": "None"
 },
 {
   "AcctID": "C429768513",
   "account_status": "INACTIVE",
   "start_date": "None",
   "end_date": "None"
 },
 {
   "AcctID": "C429768513",
   "account_status": "ACTIVE",
   "start_date": "None",
   "end_date": "None"
 },
 {
   "AcctID": "C429768513",
   "account_status": "INACTIVE",
   "start_date": "None",
   "end_date": "None"
 },
 {
   "AcctID": "C429768513",
   "account_status": "ACTIVE",
   "start_date": "None",
   "end_date": "None"
 },
 {
   "AcctID": "C429768513",
   "account_status": "INACTIVE",
   "start_date": "None",
   "end_date": "2021-12-31"
 }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(fake)
```

Edit:
Here's a fake example of what the program output could look like. Please note most of the dates are randomly chosen - but the end date of the preceding row matches the start date of the next row.

| AcctID | account_status | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | 2015-12-27 | 2016-01-05 |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | 2016-01-05 | 2016-03-01 |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | 2016-03-01 | 2017-06-22 |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | 2017-06-22 | 2017-09-04 |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | 2017-09-04 | 2018-10-27 |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | 2018-10-27 | 2019-04-04 |
| C429768513 | ACTIVE | 2019-04-04 | 2020-06-06 |
| C429768513 | INACTIVE | 2020-06-06 | 2021-12-31 |

Comment: One thing I can think of is groupby AcctID and iterate through each group. Note the index and if odd then generate random date, add it as `end_date`, then next row (even index) use this same date as `start_date`. and generate one to add as `end_date` for that row.  Manage corner cases carefully though

Comment: What would possible output look like after this program for one account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this problem :

```
df = df.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan)

def random_date(x):
    s_d = pd.to_datetime(x[x['start_date'].notna()]['start_date'])
    e_d = pd.to_datetime(x[x['end_date'].notna()]['end_date'])
    
    start_u = s_d.iloc[0].value//10**9
    end_u = e_d.iloc[0].value//10**9
    end_date_list = sorted(pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, len(x)-1), unit='s').values)
    end_date_list = np.append(end_date_list, e_d.values)
    x['end_date'] = end_date_list
    mask = x['start_date'].isna()
    x.loc[mask,'start_date'] = x.shift(1).loc[mask]['end_date'].astype(str)
    x['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(x['start_date']).dt.date
    x['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(x['end_date']).dt.date
    return x

df = df.groupby('AcctID').apply(random_date)
```

**output:**

```
        AcctID account_status  start_date    end_date
0   C382861922         ACTIVE  2016-05-25  2016-12-23
1   C382861922       INACTIVE  2016-12-23  2017-12-28
2   C382861922         ACTIVE  2017-12-28  2019-04-24
3   C382861922       INACTIVE  2019-04-24  2021-12-31
4   C429768513         ACTIVE  2015-12-27  2017-12-04
5   C429768513       INACTIVE  2017-12-04  2019-01-07
6   C429768513         ACTIVE  2019-01-07  2019-04-03
7   C429768513       INACTIVE  2019-04-03  2020-06-13
8   C429768513         ACTIVE  2020-06-13  2021-02-13
9   C429768513       INACTIVE  2021-02-13  2021-03-09
10  C429768513         ACTIVE  2021-03-09  2021-08-09
11  C429768513       INACTIVE  2021-08-09  2021-12-31
12  C643625629         ACTIVE  2016-07-24  2021-02-27
13  C643625629       INACTIVE  2021-02-27  2021-05-20
14  C643625629         ACTIVE  2021-05-20  2021-12-31
15   C82157435         ACTIVE  2016-10-22  2021-02-20
16   C82157435       INACTIVE  2021-02-20  2021-12-31
```

Comment: what is start.value in this case?  start.value//10**9   Its not defined but if its referring to s_d then that would be a series which doesn't work with .value

Comment: @Josh fixed it. can you try now

Comment: this is like black magic to me, I got pretty close but it involved 50+ lines and I still wasn't done. This is great, thank you